# Beside barchart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The basic chart functionality in R makes it relatively simple to produce a bar chart with data columns side-by-side, using the `beside` flag. For instance, this code:

```
test1 <- c(2,4)
test2 <- c(4,5)
data <- data.frame(test1, test2)
barplot(
    as.matrix(data), 
    cex.lab = 1.5, 
    cex.main = 1.4, 
    beside=TRUE
    )
```

Produces this chart:

[image]

I would like to produce a similar chart with `ggplot2`, but [the `geom_bar` function does not have a `beside` flag](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html). Can a similar bar chart be produced with `ggplot2`?

Comment: That is a different problem, qualitative data and frequencies. Here the question is how to feed a `data.frame` to `geom_bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
data$ID <- as.factor(1:nrow(data))
ggplot(melt(data, id='ID'), aes(variable, value, fill=ID, group=ID)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: None of this is obvious, even if it works quite well. What is `melt` exactly doing here? Why can't `ggplot` use a `data.frame` directly?

Comment: if you print  melt(data, id='ID') you will get an idea. Using melt it's easy to plot grouped bars.